# How to make Theano operate on Mac Lion?

Tags: python, macos, theano

I need to have Theano operate on my Mac for a school project. I downloaded sources from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Theano#downloads) (first line of the table) and put the untared file in the repertory of my school project. I didn't know if this was sufficient, so I also used `pip install Theano`. Everything seems fine since I got this :

```
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 7.0.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Theano in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6.2 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Theano)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.11 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Theano)
```

As you can see, I'm using Anaconda.

However, when I run a test in a python console, I get theses messages :

```
>>> import theano
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
>>> theano.test()
Theano version 0.7.0
theano is installed in /Users/usersos/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg/theano
NumPy version 1.9.2
NumPy is installed in /Users/usersos/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
Python version 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:37:34) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
nose version 1.3.4
/Users/usersos/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg/theano/misc/pycuda_init.py:34: UserWarning: PyCUDA import failed in theano.misc.pycuda_init
  warnings.warn("PyCUDA import failed in theano.misc.pycuda_init")
..........S.......S..S...S.S...................K.................E/Users/usersos/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/profilemode.py:103: UserWarning: DEPRECATION WARNING: The ProfileMode is deprecated. Use the Theano flags/parameter to theano.function 'profile=True' instead of 'mode=ProfileMode'
  "DEPRECATION WARNING: The ProfileMode is deprecated. Use the Theano"
.............................................................SSSSSS...SS.........S............................................................................S..................................................S......S.F.SS..SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS../Users/usersos/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg/theano/sandbox/cuda/type.py:541: UserWarning: config.experimental.unpickle_gpu_on_cpu is set to True. Unpickling CudaNdarray as numpy.ndarray
  warnings.warn("config.experimental.unpickle_gpu_on_cpu is set to True. Unpickling CudaNdarray as numpy.ndarray")
.SSSSSSSSSSSS.....KK...................S.....SSSSS
```

Is there any problem ? Are Theano and its compiler well installed ? 
I tried the first example of [this tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/adding.html) and had the same results without any bugs. But I'm wondering if there will be any bugs if I use more sophisticated functions and classes.

Comment: You chould probably get the Xcode command line tools. Also, I'd get homebrew and install a proper gcc toolchain. Then install PyCUDA using pip (pip install pycuda), if you need that. This page has a good guide: http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci104/installation/gccmac.html

Comment: In case you didn't fixed it, here is the installation instruction: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#mac-os . It tell how to get the compiled installed as the comment above suggest.

Comment: @fredrikhl Thanks for your link. Here's my follow-up to your suggestion. Any thoughts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040854/pycuda-fail-theanos-with-anaconda