# pycuda fail; Theano with Anaconda

Tags: python, xcode, theano, pycuda

I'm using Anaconda to install Theano on MacOSX (Mavericks 10.9 ), just like this post explains: "[How to make Theano operate on Mac Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398000/how-to-make-theano-operate-on-mac-lion)"

> theano.test()

This command gives the same error as in the post above. It gives that error on an Ubuntu 14.1, System 76 as well.

**I am able to import commands from Theano; but I still would like to understand why theano.test() fails. The packages CUDA and Boost were already installed before running...**

(Reference: See section: "*Testing your Installation*" http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html)

As the post suggests, I assumed the fix would come from installing the XCode command line, homebrew, and pycuda. The first two were installed just fine. But pycuda fails:

> pip install pycuda

....gives the following error:

```
    > src/cpp/cuda.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.4/src/cpp/cuda.o
    >     In file included from src/cpp/cuda.cpp:1:

> 
>     src/cpp/cuda.hpp:14:10: fatal error: 'cuda.h' file not found
>     #include <cuda.h>

>              ^
>     1 error generated.
>     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>  


    >    Command "//anaconda/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools,

    >tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/5b/5g1stsns34x_7mgynxhhvf1h0000gn/T/pip-build-4raihcb4/pycuda/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
    > 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
    > 'exec'))" install --record
    > /var/folders/5b/5g1stsns34x_7mgynxhhvf1h0000gn/T/pip-kr_3ws22-record/install-record.txt



    >> --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in

    > /private/var/folders/5b/5g1stsns34x_7mgynxhhvf1h0000gn/T/pip-build-4raihcb4/pycuda
```

It seems like the first error (gcc failed) is that the complier is not finding gcc. (Note again: I installed the MacOSX command line tools)

I run

```
which gcc
```

this gives usr/bin/gcc

I also tried :

```
python configure.py --cuda-root=/usr/local/cuda
--cuda-inc-dir=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/include --cudart-lib-dir=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/lib
```

That didn't work as well.

Has anyone else had this difficulty installing pycuda and can make a recommendation here? Thanks.

Comment: For people who might need this, here's the step-by-step install for pycuda:http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Mac  I think anacoda may handle importing modules in an unusual way. So, I'm hesitant to install using these instructions until I understand how anaconda installs modules like pycuda, in other words, I'm not sure whether it's worth installing pycuda using step 1 (for python 3.4) from the link I provided.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is not indicating that `gcc` failed to be found, rather it is saying that `gcc` reported an error and that error was that the file `cuda.h` could not be found.

That error suggests you don't have the CUDA toolkit installed. You need to install this before proceeding to install PyCUDA. The CUDA toolkit can be [downloaded from NVIDIA's website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

The [PyCUDA web page](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda/) indicates that it has the following prerequisites: BOOST, CUDA, and Numpy.

Comment: Those dependencies were installed and I still receive the same error, verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this same issue with a combination of two things:

1. Making sure `nvcc` is in your `PATH` seems resolve the compilation errors. If you then encounter the following linking error:

   `ld: file not found: @rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA for architecture x86_64
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
2. I fixed it changing the @rpath reference in libcuda.dylib to an absolute path:
   `install_name_tool -change @rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA \     /Library/Frameworks/CUDA.framework/CUDA \
   /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib`